# What answer do speakers of 'tongues' have in regard to the emphasis of scripture?

Tags: acts, 1-corinthians, pentecostalism, charismatic, speaking-in-tongues

This question regards those who support and participate in the modern 'speaking in tongues' and asks what their answer would be regarding the emphasis of scripture.

Note that it is not a matter of 'cessation' (or not). It is a matter of *emphasis.*

---

There is but one mention of tongues in the four gospel accounts, namely in Mark 16:17. Although I do not, many do dispute the acceptance of the last sixteen verses of Mark into the canon of scripture so I will pass over that single text as I assume so few would bring it up in answer to my question, that it would be regarded as moot.

**Acts**

There are two mentions in Acts which specifically refer to the apostles speaking in known foreign languages such that persons from other nations, attending the event, were able to understand those foreign languages.

Then there are two mentions more, both of specific and special occasions, one being the matter of gentiles receiving the gospel, 10:46, and then the matter of twelve receiving the gospel who had not (yet) heard of the Holy Spirit, 19:6. In neither case is it stated what, exactly, the 'tongues' were.

These four occasions are the only documented record we have of people  actually speaking in tongues and they are all special and specific occurrences upon which the tongues were a sign - a signification.

**1 Corinthians**

Paul mentions tongues twenty one times in first Corinthians (never in second Corinthians) and his quest is to regulate the matter, as it appears to have got out of hand and to have become disorderly, so he corrects the situation and applies rules.

Only if an interpreter is present can anyone speak in an unknown tongue. Paul does not comment on the *origin or the kind of the tongue* in question. He simply regulates all future utterances - of any kind - in the assembly, in such a way that all hearers, on every occasion, must be informed, intelligently - in their own mother tongue - of what is uttered at the gathering, so that all may be edified in an understandable way.

**Elsewhere**

There is no other mention that I can find of such occurrences in the Greek scriptures.

Paul does not mention the subject again to the Corinthians in his second epistle and he never mentions it in any other epistle to any other group or church. (From a purely forensic point of view, this would be circumstancial evidence that only the Corinthians were practising the procedure.)

Paul fails to mention the subject in his epistles, shortly before his death, when he instructs the younger ministers, Timothy and Titus, regarding ministerial conduct, teaching of doctrine, and matters of church government.

John fails to mention tongues in any of his four books. These books are clearly written at a later stage, clearly complete the canon of scripture and clearly contain all that is relevant to the remainder of the Church Age, prior to the Lord's return.

Peter never makes mention of tongues.

James never refers to them.

Jude, likewise.

Nor does the writer to the Hebrews, whoever that author may be.

Matthew makes no historical record in his gospel account.

Luke, likewise, in his gospel account.

---

If tongues were as central (1) a feature of church activity as some suggest, if tongues are an indication of the presence of the Holy Spirit on every occasion, if tongues are essential to the life of the church, if tongues are also essential to the edification and sound spiritual health of every single believer in the body of Christ . . . . .

. . .  then why do we see just four mentions in Acts on special occasions when a sign was necessary to mark a particular event, and why do we see just a chapter, or so, and that only when Paul regulates a matter that had got out of hand ?

Why is there silence *from every other book and from every other author* ?

Leaving aside the matter of 'cessation' that one might therefore expect that tongues - being a sign, given at a specific juncture in the inauguration of the New Testament - had ceased altogether, is it not questionable that there is a matter of emphasis to be considered ?

To be even more plain, is there not a *justifiable question of imbalance* with regard to the modern emphasis on the speaking of tongues ?

What is the response of those who participate in the speaking in tongues ?

---

Please note that I wish to read responses from persons who actively do speak in tongues, as to their thinking regarding the subject ; or to read references to those persons.

I am not looking to read theoretical assumptions from persons who do not actively practice the technique.

---

Please further note that my research was from Young's Analytical Concordance and covered every occurrence of the word tongue/tongues. It could be that this subject is alluded to in different words which I have not listed.

Also, I have deliberately not referred to the Old Testament and particularly not to prophetic passages, which require specific interpretations, e.g. Isaiah 28:11.

I am interested in keeping the inquiry (and the response) within the compass of that outlined above.

---

(1) This word added as an edit after the comment (below).

Comment: +1 best presentation I have read of the argument against the *centrality* of praying in tongues in some charismatic groups

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Edited to include your apposite word _central_. Appreciated.

Comment: +1 good question, but IMO this could be a dangerous stance to have (`why do we see just x mentions` and `Why is there silence from every other book and from every other author?`) depending on your beliefs. Can't the same be asked about any belief (for example baptism)?

Comment: @depperm Baptism is not a 'belief' it is an ordinance (which can be over-emphasised to the point where people think that by water application, souls may be automatically saved). The point about tongues is the _emphasis_ : four mentions in very specific contexts, then one chapter of corrective management which _keeps the matter in its place_.

Comment: Probably relevant: 1 Cor 14:5 *Now **I want you all to speak in tongues**, but even more to prophesy. The one who prophesies is greater than the one who speaks in tongues, unless someone interprets, so that the church may be built up.*

Comment: @NigelJ yes an ordinance, that different denomination believe differently about, and speaking in tongues is a gift of the spirit. I'm not against either, I brought up baptism as I believe it is mentioned about the same # of times. My point was I thought it an interesting stance to take when/if one believes the bible is it (no more revelation/scripture).

Comment: +1 powerful presentation

Comment: Using the same logic, couldn't one make a case against the concept of being "born again," as that phrase is used only in Jesus' conversation with Nicodemus? Yet the entire evangelical movement is based on the goal of getting everyone born again.

Comment: @RobJarvis  _anagennao_ 'born again ' _paragennesis_ 'born anew' ; born _anothen_ (born from above) and 'born of God' are all multiple expressions scattered throughout scripture. That doctrine is _certainly not_ 'used only in [one] conversation'. Not at all. There is _far more emphasis_ of that doctrine than three occasions in scripture.

Comment: @NigelJ, you stated in your question, "Please note that I wish to read responses from persons who actively do speak in tongues, as to their thinking regarding the subject ; or to read references to those persons." Perhaps you should add that you are also wanting to argue with those who have such positions. Your question only indicates that you want to receive input, not that you wish to be contentious.

Comment: @RobJarvis You asked a question without designating (by use of @) so that question defaults to the OP which in this case is myself and I have answered your question, If you wish to direct your question elsewhere then just add the @ symbol and the user's name.

Comment: The longer ending of Mark's Gospel was received in the early church as canonical. See: http://www.classicaltheism.com/snapp2/  So, I would not dismiss it so quickly for establishing doctrine.

Comment: @Jess Yes, I agree with what you say but so many do  not that I felt it pertinent not to rely on that text. Those who reject the TR will have bibles which carry in their margin a note regarding Mark 16:9-20 and mention of manuscripts such that no argument based on those verses will have any weight with them.

Comment: Nigel, surrendering the longer ending to critics - who argue it is fictional, allows an antecedent probability case down the road for the entirety of the New Testament to be considered fictional. Also, the longer ending of Mark contains a promise that is very broad in scope. It needs to be included in the argument for continuationism.

Comment: Continuationists are welcome to cite Mark 16 (in response to my question) and I will accept their argument based on that text, since I have already made clear that I accept it in the canon. I have only stated that _my own argument_ is not based on Mark 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is not what the questioner is looking for, but I believe I have the true gift of tongues, and many there be who misunderstand the gift and think speaking in some "unknown" tongue--one that no one understands--is what the Bible addresses.  I believe such an interpretation is misguided.

My gift of tongues is just like any other gift, such as the gift of healing, the gift of teaching, etc.  It must be educated, practiced, and developed.  No one (or at least extremely few) have the gift of music and just sit down and play complex music scores on the piano the first time they ever tried.  As with any gift, God gives the aptitude, and He expects us to invest our talent wisely and cause it to multiply.

I speak multiple languages fluently, and am literate in those languages, including in multiple scripts.  When I worship with other believers, I rarely have the privilege of using my mother tongue, because almost no one in the group would understand any of it.  But my linguistic gifts did not come upon me suddenly, as was granted to the apostles at Pentecost.  Such an immediate gift is rare, not only in the real world, but in the Bible itself.

David, for example, did not face Goliath having never before touched a sling.  Certainly God guided and helped him, but he had ample practice beforehand, and had slain both a lion and a bear while tending the sheep.

Daniel and his three friends did not become the wisest in Babylon overnight.  They studied diligently, on a vegetarian diet that provided them with optimal health of body and mind, for three years in the king's school.  And Daniel was a polyglot--his book is reserved for the highest levels of Hebrew classes in today's universities, as it has a mixture of multiple languages (primarily Hebrew and Syriac/Aramaic).  Daniel had the gift of tongues.

The emphasis of scripture with respect to tongues, as I see it, is that they should be used for "edification," i.e. in such a way as will benefit others.  There is no need for tongues at all in a fully monolingual congregation.  Tongues are needed when one or more persons do not understand the language being spoken.  Then an interpreter is necessary.  I have done interpretation on many occasions, even in a paid position for a church at one point in time as the church was trying to reach out to another language group in its locality.  This is where the gift of tongues is needful.

### Synopsis

The gift of tongues is only necessary and beneficial where language barriers exist and must be overcome--which I believe the apostle Paul, in his own way, was teaching.  The gift, like other gifts, must be developed and improved with exercise.  Every *good* gift is from Above, and God honors those who improve their abilities for His service.

Answer (score 1):

**Not all Christians who believe in tongues place that much emphasis on it.**

There is a subset of the Pentecostal/Charismatic movements and denominations who insist that speaking in tongues is a necessary sign of true Christianity. It is that subset that often get the attention (especially from the non-Christian media, where people doing weird things always sells). But many who believe in the supernatural gifts and practice them do not place anything like that much emphasis on tongues.

For example [Nicky Gumbel in the Alpha course](https://alpha.org/preview/alpha-with-nicky-gumbel/) includes a lecture on the Holy Spirit and talks about the Gifts of the Spirit. In this he encourages people to speak in tongues. However he makes two things very clear: 1) not everybody gets the gift of tongues. It's a gift, and God gives it to those he wants to have it 2) **he views tongues as an 'entry level' gift**. It's an easy-to-distinguish gift that identifies God's supernatural power, and it's relatively hard to do damage if you misuse it (unlike prophecy, where a false prophet could lead an entire church down a wrong path). His hope is that people who practice tongues will go on to practice the 'harder' gifts.

Nicky Gumbel writes: "Not all Christians speak in tongues, nor is it necessarily a sign of being filled with the Spirit. It is possible to be filled with the Spirit and not speak in tongues...speaking in tongues accompanies an experience of the Holy Spirit and may be the first experience of the...supernatural activity of the Spirit (Questions of Life, p. 155). Thanks Jess.

Plenty of other believers hold similar views.

Comment: Good point. Alpha does not advocate a Pentecostal "second experience" theology of the Holy Spirit. Rather, in the Alpha Course, the gifts and manifestations of the Holy Spirit are left to the total sovereignty of God. Nicky Gumbel writes: 

"Not all Christians speak in tongues, nor is it necessarily a sign of being filled with the Spirit. It is possible to be filled with the Spirit and not speak in tongues...speaking in tongues accompanies an experience of the Holy Spirit and may be the first experience of the...supernatural activity of the Spirit (Questions of Life, p. 155).

Comment: @Jess Thank you. May I edit that quote into the answer?

Comment: Yes, you can add the quote. Those who run the Alpha Course have a fundamental openness to the possibility that God may give the full range of charismatic gifts to those who pray with the receptivity of faith. That Scripture mentions the gift of tongues in only three different places  - e.g. Acts 2, 19, 1 Corinthians 11-13 & Mark 16 (i.e. with the variant Dominical longer edition), is not surprising compared to how infrequent the Lord's Supper is mentioned in the N.T.

Comment: Actually, the Bible has four different places that mention the gift of tongues explicitly. And, there is a 5th possible allusion in Roman 8 - see https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/93120/what-is-a-general-survey-of-early-catholic-exegetes-who-have-interpreted-romans

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Zac Poonen](https://www.cfcindia.com/zac-poonen) is a good candidate to [answer](https://www.cfcindia.com/article/the-truth-about-speaking-in-tongues) this question. There are also videos on YouTube of him sharing his testimony and views on the gift of tongues (e.g. [1](https://youtu.be/pUSBqeUmkQM), [2](https://youtu.be/vzY7kgkQ28M), [3](https://youtu.be/GOMvNmANWQg)). Below a (rather lengthy) quote from his article:

> #### The True And The Counterfeit
>
> There is a certain amount of mystery about the gift of tongues, as all
> those who have received the gift will acknowledge - if they are
> honest. We do not know everything about it. We know only in part (1
> Cor.13:12).
>
> **As one who has spoken in tongues for the past 45 years**, let me add a
> few words concerning what I presently understand about the gift, from
> my own experience.
>
> When a person speaks in tongues, his spirit (heart) speaks forth
> syllables (directly from his heart to his mouth, bypassing his mind)
> and thus he pours out whatever is in his heart to God - whether that
> be an overflow of joy or a burden caused by sorrow or discouragement.
> Thus the pressure on his heart is relieved. That is how he is
> 'edified'
>
> As we saw earlier in Acts 2:4, when anyone speaks in tongues, it is
> the person himself who speaks, and not the Holy Spirit. The believer
> forms the syllables himself, just as he does when speaking in a known
> language. The only difference is that now, he does NOT use a known
> language to pray, but concentrating on the Lord, speaks forth
> syllables with his mouth, straight from his heart, bypassing his mind - knowing that God understands the longings and pressures in his heart, even if he cannot understand himself what he is saying.
>
> Unburdening himself like that in moments of pressure helps a believer,
> especially if his mind is too tired to pray in a known language. We
> may not be able to explain how this works, but it does.
>
> Let us now look at the gift of interpretation: As we have already
> seen, interpretation of a tongue is equivalent to prophesying. So this
> gift will usually be given by the Spirit to one who has the gift of
> prophecy as well.
>
> In a church-meeting, if someone speaks in a tongue, one of those
> having the gift of prophecy (usually one of the elders), if he is
> walking in the light of God, will find a thought being impressed on
> his mind, if the "tongue" is genuinely from God. He speaks forth that
> thought in his own words - for it is not a translation, but an
> interpretation.
>
> If another elder (who also has the gift of interpretation) had
> interpreted the "tongue", the interpretation would have been the same
> (although couched in that elder's own words). This would be the case
> if both elders were in perfect touch with the Lord.
>
> Since no revelation from God can contradict what is written in the
> Bible, the interpretation will be in accordance with Scripture - just
> like all true prophecy will also be in line with the Scriptures.
>
> Some who are sceptical of spiritual gifts have asked this question: If
> a "tongue" that was interpreted in a meeting, is copied on to a tape
> and someone else (with the gift of interpretation) in another p lace
> is asked to interpret it, will the interpretation be the same as the
> first one? The answer is: It should be, if both interpreters had a
> perfect understanding of the mind of the Lord. If the interpretation
> is different in content,(and not just in words), that would only
> indicate that one or both interpreters are not in such perfect touch
> with the Lord as to understand His mind perfectly. That is not
> abnormal, because no believer in the world is in such perfect touch
> with the Lord as to know His mind perfectly.
>
> The following example will prove this fact beyond any doubt: Suppose
> you have to speak in a meeting and you have a particular message on
> your heart which you feel is the burden of the Lord for that meeting.
> Then, if you are unable to be at that meeting and someone else speaks
> in your stead, strictly speaking, he should give the same message as
> you had on your heart (even if it be in his own words). If that
> brother doesn't give the same message as you had on your heart, it
> would indicate that one of you did not have a perfect understanding of
> the Lord's mind for that meeting. So we see that believers could fail
> such a test even when giving a message in a known language.
>
> That's why the Bible tells us to judge even a prophet's message (1
> Cor.14:29). Similarly, we should judge, all messages in "tongues" and
> their "interpretations". What should we judge in such cases? Just
> this: Whether our spirit witnesses that the utterance (prophecy,
> tongues or interpretation) was Scriptural (and from the Lord) or not.
>
> We are warned (in 1 John 4:1) not to believe every spirit but to "test
> the spirits whether they are of God". So every time, we hear "tongues"
> or interpretation in public, we must test it in our spirits. Many of
> the "supernatural utterances" we hear may not be from God. We must
> always reject a prophecy (or any part of it), a "tongue", or an
> interpretation, if we feel uneasy about it in our spirits, for any
> reason.
>
> It is the unquestioning acceptance of everything supernatural and
> abnormal that has brought tremendous confusion into Christendom in
> this century - and tremendous dishonor to the Lord's Name as well.
>
> #### Notice these facts in all instances of speaking in tongues in "Acts":
>
> (a) In every case, the speaking in tongues was spontaneous;
> (b) In every case, all spoke in tongues - there were no exceptions;
> (c) In every case, there was no coaching or urging or instruction given on
> how to speak in tongues;
>
> Today however, in most places, none of the above characteristics are
> found. Only where the gift of tongues is spontaneously received
> without any coaching, can we conclude that it could be genuine.
>
> Of all the "speaking in tongues" that I have heard, my spirit has
> borne witness to only a small percentage of it as genuine. Most of the
> rest I have felt was an attempt to imitate the gift - either to be
> accepted by others in a group or to impress them. A small percentage
> could even be of demonic origin. My observations are based on the
> fruit and the results that I have seen in the lives of many people in
> many lands. Speaking and singing in tongues often appears to be a form
> of "exhibitionism" in many churches - and exhibitionism is
> characteristic of little children.
>
> It is also a well-established fact that, at this present time, the
> maximum exploitation of believers for financial gain is practised by
> those preachers and pastors who claim to "speak in tongues". Most of
> the cults in the 20th century have also developed from tongue-speaking
> groups.
>
> My advice to all believers therefore is: "Avoid churches that major on
> the gifts of tongues and healing - because many of them go to
> dangerous extremes and usually don't have spiritually-minded leaders.
> Seek instead for fellowship with a church that emphasises holiness and
> disciple-making primarily,that accepts the genuine gift of tongues and
> that does not covet your money or seek to control your life."
>
> Let me also emphasise that we need to use our mind (renewed by the
> Holy Spirit) if we are to understand God's will and His Word aright
> (Rom.12:2). Many believers tend to despise their minds. Our mind is to
> be like a wife. She should not be the head of the home. But she should
> not be killed either!! Jesus is our husband and head. Our mind should
> be submissive to Him through our heart.
>
> #### In a nutshell then, here is a bit of sane advice on "tongues":
>
> "If God gives you the gift of tongues, receive it and exercise it.
> Speak forth the syllables from your heart to God when you are alone
> with Him - anywhere - and especially when your heart is under pressure
> (through discouragement) or overflowing with joy. If you don't have
> the gift, don't worry about it. But be open to the Lord to receive it,
> at all times. Don't be against it and don't get into a frenzy to
> receive it. God will give it to you, if He wants you to have it,
> without any frenzy on your part. At the same time, don't believe that
> everything you see and hear in Christendom is inspired by the Holy
> Spirit. Test everything. Use your God-given faculties of discernment.
> If you don't have the gift of tongues, don't consider yourself
> inferior to those who have it. And if you do have the gift, don't
> imagine that it makes you spiritual or superior to those who don't
> have it. (Paul and the Corinthian Christians both spoke in tongues.
> But Paul was a spiritual giant, while the Corinthians were carnal!!)."
>
> #### What Is Absolutely Essential
>
> What is absolutely essential for all of us is to be endued with the
> Holy Spirit's power. It is power, and not speaking in tongues that is
> the evidence of the baptism in the Holy Spirit (Acts 1:8).
>
> The Holy Spirit is to be received by faith (Jn.7:37-39), just as we
> received the forgiveness of our sins - on the basis of Christ's merit
> alone, and not on our own merit. We do not receive the Gift of the
> Spirit by fasting or praying or by any other work. He is a Gift (Acts
> 2:38).
>
> We ask and receive - immediately by faith - and go forth believing in
> God's promise that He gives the Holy Spirit more readily to those who
> ask Him,than any earthly father would give food to a hungry son
> (Lk.11:13). If we are unsure about having received the Spirit, we can
> ask God to give us an assurance. He will not deny us such an
> assurance.
>
> But we need to be filled with the Spirit continually (because we are
> leaky vessels - Eph.5:18), just like we need to be forgiven
> continually (because we sin - often without knowing it - Matt.6:12).
>
> The devotion of our heart to Christ is far more important than our
> speaking in tongues."Do you love Me more than everything else?", was
> our Lord's question to Peter, before commissioning him for His
> service. Arguments about "speaking in tongues" are therefore a
> diversion arranged by Satan to sidetrack believers from total devotion
> to Christ.
>
> The greatest Christians in the world have been those who loved the
> Lord Jesus supremely - whether they spoke in tongues or not. Some like
> Peter, James, John and Paul spoke in tongues. Others like John Wesley,
> Charles Finney, D.L.Moody, A.B.Simpson, William Booth, C.T.Studd and
> Watchman Nee never spoke in tongues (as far as we know). But they all
> received the baptism in the Holy Spirit, they all loved the Lord with
> all their hearts and they ALL walked the way of the cross. These
> truths were central in their lives. Other things were secondary.
>
> Let us follow their example and we won't go wrong..
>
> He who has ears to hear, let him hear.

Comment: 1. This answer is stating that a person's thoughts (his 'heart') are his own (not an angel's, not the Holy Spirit's, not God's, not heaven's) and - for some unexplained reason this seems to bypass the vocal part of his brain and he utters 'syllables'. This does not accord with the four texts of scripture stated above. 2. This answer claims that 'Peter, James, John and Paul' spoke in tongues : the only known occurrence was when the first three spoke _known languages_ on the day of Pentecost (without interpretation) and hearers understood those languages, they being words in their mother tongue.

Comment: @NigelJ - feel free to send an email to Zac Poonen, I'm just sharing his answer.

Comment: _Poonen has been very sharp in his critique of today's free church, **especially its charismatic part.**_ [Zac Poonen Wikipedia](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zac_Poonen).

Comment: @NigelJ - Yet he speaks in tongues, as requested in the question. He is against the excesses of 'hyper-charismatics', but he's a continuationist nonetheless.

Comment: As a tongue-talking Christian, the only critique I would have of Poonen's conclusions is that, scripturally, it is the Spirit who "gives the utterance"—in other words, yes, the person's spirit (or heart) is praying, but it should be emphasized that the born-again spirit of a person is in full unity and agreement with the Holy Spirit, who __provides the specific words__ to express the human spirit's thoughts and feelings.

Comment: @RobJarvis So the 'syllables' uttered are (you say) words from the Holy Spirit, not from the mind or heart of the speaker ? _For the Holy Ghost shall teach you in the same hour what ye ought to say._ Luke 12:12. Then he gives words that no-one can understand (unless an interpreter be present) ? ? ?

Comment: @NigelJ, my point is that the spirit of the Christian is in perfect unity with the Holy Spirit, while maintaining a distinct identity. There is never a conflict between spirit and Holy Spirit, only between flesh and spirit, or between soul (mind/will/emotions) and Holy Spirit. Thus, I think you are maybe trying to draw too fine a line. Paul said, "For if I pray in an unknown tongue, my spirit prayeth, but my understanding is unfruitful." (1 Cor. 14:14 KJV). So the human spirit prays, using words that the Holy Spirit imparts.

Comment: Additionally, @NigelJ, no interpretation is needed when the Christian prays in tongues during private prayer time.

Answer (score 0):

From a layman speaking my heart on the tongues issue. I have spoken in tongues for about 25 years. I find the vast majority of the time tongues flows out of me during my praise & worship of God. But occasionally I have spoken a tongue to the body... it has only come forth that way by a strong urge from the Holy Spirit;
mainly because of the interpretation parameter Paul lays out. Not being sure if someone would interpret or would speak up to interpret has kept me from speaking out more often. Also my "walk" condition at the time has held me in check as well.

We see in Acts 19:5-6, when the Holy Spirit came on them, they spake with tongues and prophesied. These were brand new believers in Christ...only 1 verse before!

As to emphasis and stated by others, a correct tongue will be witnessed by the bible... if not by specific word or verse then absolutely by the spirit or tenor and tone of the bible. A proper word or prayer or edification in tongues will never contradict the character of God.

How important is tongues to the believer? 1Cor 14:39, 40.

Before I close, I have heard it said... a lot, that tongues must be of a known language or possibly a language that has been before...? Well that is certainly true if I begin speaking German to a German for his benefit to hear God's council. But what of "your" prayer language... if satan has been here manipulating humans for thousands of years, maybe he learned all the languages along the way... maybe he shouldn't know what the Holy Spirit is conversing to God the Father about on my behalf. Most times after praying in tongues I ask the Lord to translate them for me... so that I have personal knowledge of what the Holy Spirit says I have need of, then I can be in agreement as well. Most of the time thoughts will come shortly that I recognize are not mine and the few times He didn't tell me, when I asked why... He said "you don't need to know yet".

Our ways are not His ways and our thoughts are not His thoughts.  When His thoughts come, at least for me, they're easily recognizable.

My doctrine is Jesus and Him crucified. My walk is the best I can allow Him to live thru me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, "Holy Spirit is conversing to God the Father" do you have a scriptural reference for this occurrence?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: @steveowen - Romans 8:26-27 *26 Likewise the Spirit helps us in our weakness. For we do not know what to pray for as we ought, **but the Spirit himself intercedes for us with groanings too deep for words**. 27 And he who searches hearts knows what is the mind of the Spirit, because **the Spirit intercedes for the saints according to the will of God**.*

Comment: Close but only of you read in what you are looking for. The disciples express the Spirit IS the Father - we don't need to complicate it with "he" everywhere and make up a 'conversing to God' spirit.

Comment: I suppose the Godhead (F, S & H S) do not naturally converse with each other. I think hearing by one party of another party is part of a conversation. Jn 16:13 & Rms 8:27 together show a "conversation" going on.

Comment: And for "me", a tongue talker... the emphasis this gift has proven to me... at my most trying times during my walk, when none where around or were but I wouldn't trust them; talking to God in tongues undergirded me, pulled me thru, led me to solid ground... carried me when my strength and will were gone... ready to chuck it all, "this stuff don't work it's all a charade": crying and heart ripping out of my chest... BUT HE was there, He hadn't given up! Things had gotten so forlorn that He could now work and work He did. Jesus saved me forever the Holy Spirit saves me daily (my wording).

Comment: Well, typical... shoulda' did the tour first! Thx agarza. Bull in the china closet. Sorry folks, I will endeavor to moderate my moderatin'.

Answer (score -1):

#### The question of emphasis

The OP's question is about the *emphasis* placed on tongues by some Pentecostal and Charismatic groups, considering the relative paucity of scriptural occurrences of the specific term "tongues." I would like to address that idea specifically.

In response, I don't believe that frequency of use in Scripture is a valid rubric for emphasis in worship. If we think about other words in Scripture and whether or not most Protestant denominations emphasize those doctrines or topics, the disparity should be obvious.

For example, a quick trip into *Strong's Exhaustive Concordance* shows that the words "heaven" and "heavens" combined occur some 715 times in the KJV. Now, some of those references are to the atmospheric heavens (what we call the "sky"), some are for the celestial heavens, while many refer to the domain of God's throne. Still others in the gospels—Matthew especially—are part of the phrase "kingdom of heaven," referring to God's rule and reign either in the lives of the believer or in the world to come. Even discounting the atmospheric and celestial references, there remain hundreds of references to either God's abode or the specific rule and reign of God on earth. Now, following the idea that frequency in Scripture should equate to emphasis in church, I would expect to hear a great deal more about Heaven and Kingdom living and principles than I actually do. (Now, if you are thinking, "Well, *my* church *does* emphasize those things," I say good, but I am speaking about the totality of Protestantism, not just one denomination or church group.)

Let's consider another example: the Sabbath. Aside from the Seventh Day Adventists and some Messianic groups, I daresay not many denominations or churches place great emphasis or spend much time talking about the Sabbath. Yet *Strong's* reveals 172 mentions of Sabbath/Sabbaths in the KJV. Surely we should be emphasizing the Sabbath more than tongues or many other doctrines that have lesser representation (by word count) in Scripture.

In fact, I don't know of any church group or denomination that uses the frequency of a word or doctrine to determine the emphasis they place on that doctrine in their teachings. Instead, I see *emphasis* as being based on something else entirely.

#### Emphasis is based on culture and history

If you consider church history during and since the Protestant Reformation, you will see many denominational groups formed when a portion of one group began to disagree with their current leadership with regard to one or more doctrinal issues. (I know I'm oversimplifying, but can we agree that this has happened too often to discount?) The resulting splinter group would form its own denomination, which would then *tend* to emphasize the issue or issues that caused the split to begin with.  Protestant denominations commonly acknowledge the centrality of the death, burial and resurrection of Jesus Christ, yet it tends to be the areas of difference that often end up being emphasized. This is history and culture at work—the history of that particular denomination and the culture in which its participants were raised. The anti-papal culture of the Seventh-Day Adventists drips from every page of their eschatology. The Reformation cry of "Sola Scriptura" echoes in every Presbyterian sermon. And "being baptized in the Holy Ghost with the evidence of speaking in tongues" is interwoven into the culture of American Pentecostalism. To the extent that there is *any* scriptural evidence for these positions (or any other doctrinal positions), there will be groups who emphasize them regardless of how great or how small that evidence is.

For me, as a Charismatic Christian, the evidence for tongues and the instruction for the proper use of this gift in Scripture is sufficient for me to accept it. I do not emphasize it as many do, but I understand and sympathize with the motivations of those who do.

The caveat I have with regard to emphasizing tongues is that other gifts of the Spirit (and indeed the Holy Spirit Himself) tend to get short shrift in doctrine and practice by those who are preoccupied with speaking in tongues. This applies to those who are against speaking in tongues as well as those who are for it. Emphasis works both ways.